# Launch Composed Nodes using the launch XML Frontend

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I've been looking through the new launch_ros xml/yaml frontend design and parsing recently, and noticed that there doesn't seem to be a way currently to launch composed nodes through this frontend? It looks as if the parser, when in python, uses the frontend to generate a Node, and thus not a ComposableNode let alone a ComposableNodeContainer.

Is there currently a plan to include launching composable nodes at all via the launch frontend? It seems quite important especially since there is a way to do so using the old ROS1 nodelet API.

EDIT: Some links to provide context

As an example, [this](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/composition/launch/composition_demo.launch.py) is the current workflow for launch composition nodes using the launch_ros python interface.

Looking at the [design](https://github.com/ros2/design/blob/gh-pages/articles/151_roslaunch_xml.md) of the roslaunch XML frontend. The only allowed tags which would launch a process would be executable and node.

In the [node.py](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/master/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/node.py) file in launch_ros, special provisions and imports were made to expose this action to the frontend, but it seems that currently the [composable_node_container.py](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/master/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/composable_node_container.py) does not have any similar implementations.

Since this feature is not mentioned in either the design or the implementation, I wonder if this is something that the frontend is planned to support?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333404/launch-composed-nodes-using-the-launch-xml-frontend/) by [eric1221bday](https://answers.ros.org/users/30851/eric1221bday/) on ROS Answers with karma: 245 on 2019-09-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-09-19**:
Please edit your question to include links to what you're reading and where you're referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi eric1221bday,

The design document you're referring to is actually a format, and the implementation is not limited to just those tags.
We started by writing the "parsing functions" of the tags that were available in roslaunch XML, but new ones can be easily added.

Here is [Node's](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/d25e2b334897b9c4526b1dcd1c8025debc245737/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/node.py#L174-L252) parsing function as an example.

The following actions will need a parsing function to get the functionality you're asking for:

- https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/d25e2b334897b9c4526b1dcd1c8025debc245737/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/composable_node_container.py#L31
- https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/d25e2b334897b9c4526b1dcd1c8025debc245737/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/load_composable_nodes.py#L35

I'm not currently planning to add it, contributions are welcomed.
Also, you can ping me if you have any question.

Best,
Regards

---

Originally posted by [ivanpauno](https://answers.ros.org/users/44086/ivanpauno/) with karma: 86 on 2019-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eric1221bday](https://answers.ros.org/users/30851/eric1221bday/) on 2019-09-19**:
Thanks for the response. Since this would entail extending the current XML frontend tags, I'll have to put some more thought into it. But perhaps a  tag might work?

**Comment by [ivanpauno](https://answers.ros.org/users/44086/ivanpauno/) on 2019-09-20**:
I would use the following tags:

- `node_container`
- `load_composable_node`
- `composable_node`

The last tag is for the [composable node description](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/d25e2b334897b9c4526b1dcd1c8025debc245737/launch_ros/launch_ros/descriptions/composable_node.py), which doesn't have to be exposed with [expose_action](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/d25e2b334897b9c4526b1dcd1c8025debc245737/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/node.py#L56) as the others.

For this one, I would recommend writing a free function that does the parsing, and you can reuse it from both `node_container` and `load_composable_node` actions.

**Comment by [eric1221bday](https://answers.ros.org/users/30851/eric1221bday/) on 2019-09-21**:
So looking at the API here, it occurs to me that I'm not sure if the current API will allow for loading composable nodes in separate launch files. The current `LoadComposableNode` has a target_container argument which is required to be a `ComposableNodeContainer` and beyond that it also requires it to have already been executed. Am I missing something? Or does this mean that the current system cannot allow for launching the node container in one launch file and then launching components targeting that container in other launch files.

**Comment by [ivanpauno](https://answers.ros.org/users/44086/ivanpauno/) on 2019-09-23**:
That's a good question.
The current implementation of `LoadComposableNodes` needs the target container at construction, but if you see the implementation detail, the only needed thing is the node name.
I would add a new argument to the constructor: `node_name`.
One of `node_name` and `target_container` should be required (IMO, `target_container` should be deprecated).

The topic of having references (i.e.: being able to identify) another action in the XML/YAML frontend is an interesting feature currently not supported.
It would be useful, for example, to support event handlers.

**Comment by [eric1221bday](https://answers.ros.org/users/30851/eric1221bday/) on 2019-09-23**:
Yeah I’ve actually since then gonna ahead and implemented this exact idea, though in my case i made target container a Union so as to not disrupt the current API. The pull request is [here](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/pull/77)